# I want to make symlinks of all files in a directory EXCEPT the existing symlinks in the directory

Tags: bash, symlink, ln

I have a bash script that creates symlinks from the directories in one users directory to another users directory. I want the script to exclude existing symlinks in the source directory when creating symlinks.

Comment: Looks like you're reinventing [`stow`](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with stow, is that similar to "install"? Also, I am on MacOs, so stow is not available for me right now. I will check it out.

Comment: `stow` is much more. It's used for managing symlinks to files from one directory to another. Lets you add, update, remove groups of symlinks. It's available via homebrew.

Comment: I think I have to find another approach. Is there a way to find and remove files with a pattern like this (where the pattern is only that there are two underscores in the filename, separated by letters or numbers) file_name_name

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the `-L` operator.

```
user@debian:~$ touch file
user@debian:~$ ln -s file link
user@debian:~$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 avril  8 12:01 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    4 avril  8 12:01 link -> file
user@debian:~$ if [[ -L file ]]; then echo "it's a link"; fi
user@debian:~$ if [[ -L link ]]; then echo "it's a link"; fi
it's a link
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that option is not available on MacOS..